# Is it possible to display the debug bar while NOT logged in?

Tags: users, performance, devmode, debugging

I'm trying to solve some possible performance issues caused in the logic of my site which checks for whether a user is logged in or not, to display or not display certain pieces of content.

**Is it possible to use the debug toolbar in a browser window where I'm NOT logged in?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an option in craft to do that, but if you really wanted  to do this you can create your module and add this code inside the init function.

```
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
$request->getHeaders()->set('X-Debug','enable');
```

Also don't forget to add your module to bootstrap.